# Correct way to require files within a RubyGem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I used Bundler to generate a Gem skeleton for me. Within `lib/foo.rb`, I have the following:

```
require 'foo/client'
require 'foo/other'
```

Those two lines are supposed to require `lib/foo/client.rb` and `lib/foo/other.rb`, respectively. It builds without a problem, but when I go to test it with `irb`, I get a file not found error.

```
ruby-1.9.2-head :003 > require 'foo'
LoadError: no such file to load -- foo/client
    from /home/ethan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/ethan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/foo-0.1.0/lib/foo.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ethan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/ethan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from (irb):3
    from /home/ethan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
ruby-1.9.2-head :004 >
```

What is the correct way to require files within the same Gem? There must be something simple that I'm overseeing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current directory is not in the load path in Ruby 1.9. Try one of these:

```
require './client'
```

or

```
require_relative 'client'
```

Comment: Using require_relative, I'm still getting errors. https://gist.github.com/1288893

Answer (score 5):

If your gem is called 'foo', then all you need to do is use `bundle exec`:

```
bundle exec your-script.rb
```

Without bundle exec, the load paths are not set up correctly.

Using irb, you use the bundle command `bundle console`.

```
chris@chris:~/oss/pp-adaptive$ irb
irb(main):001:0> AdaptivePayments
NameError: uninitialized constant Object::AdaptivePayments
    from (irb):1
    from /home/chris/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0> 

chris@chris:~/oss/pp-adaptive$ bundle console
irb(main):001:0> AdaptivePayments
=> AdaptivePayments
irb(main):002:0>
```

Note that once the gem is installed on your system, you may use it without bundler.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in IRB itself you may have to

```
require "rubygems"
require "foo"
```

if the library is a gem. Alternatively you can require the full path of the gem, but I wouldn't advise it since rubygems does require magic so `reload!` works in irb ( at least it does for rails console ).